# Problem adding textboxes dynamiclly in a relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am having trouble dynamically adding a text box to my view. More specifically, the text-box-adder works, but the button I am trying to move below it does not. The original view is the first picture in the below hyperlink.

After the +/- button is pressed, it should add a text box between the second text box and the decide button, and then move the +/- button down so it is next to the new box. Instead, the second picture happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzBL3.png

My code looks like this:

```
EditText textBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.box2);

            RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            EditText newText = new EditText(context);

            newText.setId(numBoxes);
            numBoxes++;

            LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, bottomView.getId());
            p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, bottomView.getId());
            newText.setWidth(220);
            newText.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            newText.setLayoutParams(p);
            rel.addView(newText);
            bottomView = newText;
            ((TextView) bottomView).setText((CharSequence)bottomView.getTag());

            LayoutParams b = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            Button goButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.decide);
            b = (LayoutParams) goButton.getLayoutParams();
            b.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, bottomView.getId());
            goButton.setLayoutParams(b);

            Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addsub);
            b = (LayoutParams) addButton.getLayoutParams();
            b.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, textBox2.getId());
            b.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, bottomView.getId());
            addButton.setLayoutParams(b);
```

Numboxes is just a counter so I can keep track of the boxes and name them accordingly, and bottomView is just the bottom-most text box.

I have searched all over the android development pages, and tried creating the new layout params. I also tried replacing the decide button with a text box, bu the same problem occurred. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

For those that care, I'm part of this development team and we got our problem solved.

Here is the problem concept.

```
LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

In our layout, we're using a relative layout, thus the line should be:

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Assigning incompatible layout parameters causes problems.